# PHP + Jquery, как понять что пользователь находится на сайте (даже не зарегестрированный)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Мне нужно понимать, что пользователь находится на сайте.

Моим решением выступает то что 1 раз в минуту я буду отправлять ajax запрос на сервак, значит пользователь еще на сайте.

На стороне сервера проверять онлайн пользователей и если по времени он уже неактив как 5 минут - значит не на сайте и ставить ему статус оффлайн.

А если пользователь откроет 20 вкладок , то получается отправится 20 запросов
Как этого избежать?

Или посоветуйте пожалуйста готовые решения для данной проблемы. Спасибо!

Comment: Отправляйте при каждой загрузке страницы "я онлайн", а через 5 минут бездействия "я оффлайн", и смотрите по времени, если "я онлайн" >= 5 минут значит действительно человек оффлайн

Comment: Записывайте в localStorage таймштамп последнего запроса "я онлайн" на сервер, а перед отправкой очередного проверяйте, прошла ли минута с того момента. Так из всех вкладок отправлять запросы будет одна